# How can I remove duplicate entries in linux log

Tags: sed, cut, uniq, logs

I've turned mysql general log on and I've been logging every transaction that occurs for the last week. I also have a cronjob running every 5 minutes doing some mysql transactions which is polluting my log. I would like to know how I can remove those entries from my log so it would look more clean.

The repetitive entries from cron look like this:

```
160614 16:45:01    36 Connect   user@localhost on 
                   36 Init DB   db1
                   36 Query     SELECT FROM status_history as sh INNER JOIN (SELECT work_order_i
d, MAX(status_changed) AS MaxDateTime FROM status_history GROUP BY work_order_id) as groupedsh ON sh.work_order_id = groupedsh.work_o

                            JOIN rchetype_work_order_views AS wov ON wo.id = wov.work_order_id
                                WHERE wov.viewed = 0 AND sh.status_id IN (SELECT status_id FROM rchetype_status_completed)
                   36 Quit
```

I was thinking in using sed but the problem is that he first line will obviouslly have a different date and different transaction number (in this case 36) and I would like to delete all lines until it finds the first Quit at the end. So I was wondering if there's a way to do this. I'm just looking for ideas.

Comment: Any specific string which is constant on first line I.e date line ?

Comment: @Rahul yes, `Connect   user@localhost on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that they are always the same amount of lines, you could do something like this:
`sed '/Connect\s*user@localhost on/,+7d' log.file`
This will remove the line containing `Connect   user@localhost on` and the following 7 lines from the file "log.file" in your current directory.

Edit: final solution (well, at least good enough for the OP to alter to his liking) can be found in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kaffe, I don't know if there are always the same amount of lines, but in any case, isn't possible to tell sed to remove until it finds the next Quit word?

Comment: Something like this? `sed '/Connect *user@localhost on/,/36 Quit/{/(user|Quit)/!d}' tmp.file`

Comment: Of course, assuming it's always "36 Quit". You can replace that with maybe just "Quit" or this: `sed '/Connect\s*user@localhost on/,/[0-9][0-9] Quit/{/(user|Quit)/!d}' tmp.file`

Comment: Thank you, that's very close to what I'm looking for! however it doesn't work in some of the logs I have so I'm trying to modify your regex, could you explain what `/{/(user|Quit)/!d}` does? So I can modify it? thanks. And by the way it's not always '36 Quit' I did [0-9]* Quit since I don't know how many digits the transaction number will have.

Comment: The first part tells sed the range and the second in the curly brackets are applied to the range. If nothing is in there, like `{//!d}`, you'll get the lines where the range starts and ends. Now, I have to admit, I didn't do that right, even if it yielded the right result for me. Replace that with this `sed '/Connect\s*user@localhost on/,/[0-9]* Quit/{/^.*$/d}' tmp.file`, which tells it do delete everything that starts and ends with anything within the range, in other words -- delete's the unwanted data.

Comment: Really nice, thank you very much, I still have to do some other adjustments but that was very helpful.